# How to avoid Table Lock Escalation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, extended-events, lock-escalation, batch-processing

I've got a task to update 5 million rows in a production table, without locking down the whole table for extended time

So, I used approach that helped me before many times - updating top (N) rows at a time with 1-N second interval between chunks

This time started with update top (1000) rows at a time, monitoring the Extended Events session for `lock_escalation` events in the process

`lock_escalation` showed up during each update operation, so I started lowering row count per chunk `1000 -> 500 -> 200 -> 100 -> 50` rows and so on down to 1

Before (not with this table, and for delete operations - not update), lowering row count to 200 or 100, helped to get rid of `lock_escalation` events
But this time, even with 1 row per 1 update operation, table `lock_escalation` still shows up. Duration of each update operation is about the same, regardless if its 1 row or 1000 rows at a time

How to get rid of table lock escalations in my case ?

@@TRANCOUNT is zero

Extended event:

[image: Extended Event]

[Code](https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools/blob/master/Update%20in%20chunks.sql):

```
set nocount on

declare 
    @ChunkSize              int = 1000,                         -- count rows to remove in 1 chunk 
    @TimeBetweenChunks      char(8) = '00:00:01',               -- interval between chunks
    
    @Start                  datetime,
    @End                    datetime,
    @Diff                   int,
    
    @MessageText            varchar(500),
    
    @counter                int = 1,
    @RowCount               int = 1,
    @TotalRowsToUpdate      bigint,
    @TotalRowsLeft          bigint
    


-- total row count to update
set @TotalRowsToUpdate = (select count(*)
                            from [Table1]
                                join [Table2] on
                                    btid = tBtID
                            where   btStatusID = 81)


set @TotalRowsLeft = @TotalRowsToUpdate
set @MessageText = 'Total Rows to Update = ' + cast(@TotalRowsLeft as varchar) raiserror (@MessageText,0,1) with nowait
print ''



-- begin cycle
while @RowCount > 0 begin

    set @Start = getdate()

    -- update packages
    update top (@ChunkSize) bti
        set btstatusid = 154,
            btType = 1
    from [Table1] bti
        join [Table2] on
            btid = tBtID
    where   btStatusID = 81
    

    set @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

    -- measure time
    set @End = getdate()
    set @Diff = datediff(ms,@Start,@End)

    set @TotalRowsLeft = @TotalRowsLeft - @RowCount
    set @MessageText = cast(@counter as varchar) + ' - Updated ' + cast(@RowCount as varchar) + ' rows in ' + cast(@Diff as varchar) + ' milliseconds - total ' + cast(@TotalRowsLeft as varchar) + ' rows left...'

    -- print progress message
    raiserror (@MessageText,0,1) with nowait


    set @counter += 1

    WAITFOR DELAY @TimeBetweenChunks

end
```

Plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyozGWMLw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we look at the actual plan, the current query is reading too much data from the table to be updated.  This is from the index seek on `BoxTrackInfo`:

[image: screenshot of index seek operator details]

This is an index seek on `btid` for each row that comes out of the scan of `BlueTrackEvents`.  Update locks are acquired as `btStatusID` is checked to see if the row qualifies for the update.  Only 1,401 rows qualify for the update, but many more locks are taken in the process - resulting in lock escalation to the table level.

You really want a different plan shape - to seek into the `BoxTrackInfo` table on `btStatusID` and then join to `BlueTrackEvents`, which should acquire significantly less locks.  To that end, adding an index like this should help:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_btStatusID 
ON dbo.BoxTrackInfo (btStatusID)
INCLUDE (btType);
```

This should more efficiently locate qualifying rows, hopefully allowing the update to complete without lock escalation.

---

As a side note, the current execution plan validates the foreign key constraint on `btStatusID` using a merge semi-join:

[image: screenshot of execution plan showing merge join FK validation]

This is probably not a big deal in your case, since there are only 267 rows in the `LBoxTrackStatus` table.  If that table were larger, you might consider adding a `LOOP JOIN` or `FAST 1` hint to the query in order to get nested loops FK validation.  See this post for details:

[Why am I getting a snapshot isolation issue on INSERT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248585/why-am-i-getting-a-snapshot-isolation-issue-on-insert)